# UWP App in multiple languages

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml

I am developing a UWP app and I liked that I was available in several languages. I'm using visual studio 2015, how do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

good start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/globalizing/globalizing-portal

in essence: set x:Uid element in your xaml. In your resource file do [x:Uid].[PropertyName]

so for example:

in resource file the key for the text proeprty will be tb1.Text

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, create the following folder structure in your app project:

```
\Strings
\Strings\en-US
\Strings\it-IT
```

Then add a new file: `Resources.resw` in each of the last two folders which type is `Resource File`,

Add a `TextBlock` control in the main page, set the property `x:Uid="TextWelcome"`, then in each `Resources.resw`, add a new item:

```
Name: TextWelcome.Text
Value: (your localized string)
```

Build and launch app, change the culture of your machine, then check the localized version of your app.

Here is an article and a sample app project for your reference:

[Windows 10 Development - Localization](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/windows10_development/windows10_development_localization.htm)

[Sample app - Localization in Windows 10](https://github.com/qmatteoq/UWPLocalization)